# Set the class string to empty

Tags: c#, database

This is the class and the string is the database column, how can I set the column to empty, when i want to call it out? Is string strDockey = string.Empty;??

```
  public class SL_CS
        {
            public string strDocKey { get; set; }
            public string strDocNo { get; set; }
            public string strDOCDATE { get; set; }
            public string strPOSTDATE { get; set; }
            public string strTAXDATE { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: can i set Console.WriteLine("Empty? {0}", sl_cs.strDocKey == String.Empty); below the code or need to write it into cs file,because up there is class file

Comment: You need to mention how you talk to the database.  EntityFramework, Linq-to-sql, Dapper, etcetera.  Probably `null` to indicate "no value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your properties in the constructor of your class:

```
public class SL_CS{

    // constructor gets called when you new this class
    public SL_CS{ 
        // set any properties as you would do normally 
        sl_cs.strDocKey = String.Empty; 
    }

    public string strDocKey { get; set; }
    public string strDocNo { get; set; }
    public string strDOCDATE { get; set; }
    public string strPOSTDATE { get; set; }
    public string strTAXDATE { get; set;}
}
```

When you now new your class:

```
var inst = new SL_CS();
```

and then inspect `inst.strDocKey` it will be String.Empty. Your other properties will be null.